# Why are shapes with sharp corners structually weak?

Tags: structural-engineering

Please explain my question like I'm 5 too? [ELI5: Why do ships have circular windows instead of square ones? : explainlikeimfive](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/gz5idy/eli5_why_do_ships_have_circular_windows_instead/)

> The real answer is that **shapes with sharp corners are structurally weak**. Arcs and circles are very strong shapes. If port holes were squares, the openings would get damaged and worn out sooner.

Comment: What did you find not clear in the answer? It is all mentioned: radiusing, fatigue, the comet ircraft etc plenty to drive your further research.

Comment: An internal corner produces a stress concentration, so local stress is well above the nominal stress.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_concentration

Answer (score 4):

*Stress* is a physical quantity that averages over internal forces (e.g. van der Waals forces, Ionic bonding, collisions, ...) that neighbouring atoms/molecules of a material exert on each other.

If a force acts on an object, it causes stress inside the material. Stress behaves like a fluid in the sense that stress *flows* trough the material. Now, if there is a sharp corner, stress can't flow around it which causes a concentration of stress in that point.

If the stress in that region is to high, the material will fail. Therfore having round corners instead of sharp corners can make a structure stronger. The following picture from Wikipedia illustrates this quite well:

[image: Picture from Wikipedia illustrating the flow of stress]

Comment: See [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26514/why-do-stress-concentrations-really-occur) in turn for a discussion of what those mysterious lines are intended to mean.